# Check if a value exists in a dataset or column

Tags: sas

I have a macro program with a loop `(for i in 1 to n)`. With each `i` i have a table with many columns - variables. In these columns, we have one named `var` (who has 3 possible values: a b and c).

So for each table `i`, I want to check his column `var` if it exists the value "c". If yes, I want to export this table into a sheet of excel. Otherwise, I will concatenate this table with others.

Can you please tell me how can I do it?

Comment: Hello Quang, would you post your code here and with sample data and what you have previously tried?

Comment: @VasilijNevlev : I tried directly on my project and its very long so i don't know how should i post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in your macro at step i you have to do something like this

```
proc sql;
select min(sum(case when var = 'c' then 1 else 0 end),1) into :trigger from table_i;
quit;
```

then, you will get macro variable *trigger* equal 1 if you have to do export, and 0 if you have to do concatenetion. Next, you have to code something like this

```
%if &trigger = 1 %then %do;
proc export data = table_i blah-blah-blah;
run;
%end;
%else %do;
data concate_data;
set concate_data table_i;
run;
%end;
```

Comment: Hello , is it normal that the sum function return '.'  if table_i has 0 observation?

Comment: It worked; thanks !  I just changed a bit on the code. I calculated only the SUM. If its >= 1 i will do the export. I don't use the Min because if the data has 0 observation the sum will return '.' , it will make the min always = 1.

Comment: to avoid '.' in case of 0 observation, you can code max(min(...,1),0) - so you get max(.,0) = 0

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the whole nine yard of your problem, I am at risk to say that you may not need Macro at all, if you don't mind exporting to .CSV instead of native xls or xlsx. IMHO, if you do 'Proc Export', meaning you can't embed fancy formats anyway, you 'd better off just use .CSV in most of the settings. If you need to include column headings, you need to tap into metadata (dictionary tables) and add a few lines.

```
filename outcsv '/share/test/'; /*define the destination for CSV, change it to fit your real settings*/

/*This is to Cat all of the tables first, use VIEW to save space if you must*/
data want1;
set table: indsname=_dsn;
dsn=_dsn;
run;

/*Belowing is a classic 2XDOW implementation*/
data want;
file outcsv(test.csv) dsd; /*This is your output CSV file, comma delimed with quotes*/
do until (last.dsn);
  set want1;
   by dsn notsorted; /*Use this as long as your group is clustered*/
   if var='c' then _flag=1; /*_flag value will be carried on to the next DOW, only reset when back to top*/
end;

do until (last.dsn);
  set want1;
   by dsn notsorted;
   if _flag=1 then put (_all_) (~); /*if condition meets, output to CSV file*/
   else output; /*Otherwise remaining in the Cat*/
end;
drop dsn _flag;
run;
```